# react-native <Image> using either a uri or an image path

Tags: react-native

I have the following piece of code:

```
const placeholder = '../images/placeholder.png';
const filePath = 'file://aaa/bbb.png';

return (
  <View>
     {imageLoaded?
         <Image
            source={{ uri: imageFilePath }} /> :
         <Image
            source={require(placeholder)} />
     }
  </View>
)
```

Is there a way to set a source variable and use it intead?

Something like:

```
const image1 = ???
const image2 = require(placeholder);

const imagePath = imageLoaded? image1 : image2;

return (
  <View>
     <Image source={imagePath} />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: I suggest you try your second piece of code; You are almost there. One slight improvement is that you could import your images withing your file (import image1 ...; import image2) and then do as you wrote (imageLoaded ? image1 : image2)

This helps avoid requiring your image at each render, I guess it will not be as smooth as importing images only 1 time through the bridge. But it has been a more than 6 months since I react-native so maybe it has a cache enabled for images, dunno. (I digress)

Comment: Importing wouldn't be convenient in this case...

Comment: I didn't get the question properly, but if what I understood is correct. You can require both the images beforehand `let image1 = require('image-url-you-want');` and then use `const imagePath = imageLoaded? image1 : image2;` Then you can  use `<Image source={imagePath}/>`

Comment: What should I write in the case of the uri?